# Need an Excel formula to be changed to work in Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, sumproduct

Trying to get a count based on cells in two different columns that I have in a Google Sheets file linked to my Data Studio dashboard - I want to count all cells in column A that have a value, but I only want these values to be counted if there is no value in a cell in column B Ex. of what this would look like in Excel: A2 = 2020-08-19, B2 = *B2 is blank

In Excel, this formula is:

=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(A2:A6)>0)*(LEN(B2:B6)=0))

What would be the Data Studio equivalent to this? Data Studio does not accept SUMPRODUCT. I'm putting this count into a table in Data Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by using the [`CASE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) statement below, where `Field_A` represents the Date field (`Column A`), and `Field_B` represents `Column B`:

```sql
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN Field_B IS NULL THEN Field_A
    ELSE NULL END)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/28878a78-5d41-47d7-874f-8955d56abae7) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]